Bijection between orderings of $\mathbb{R}(X)$ and Dedekind cuts in $\mathbb{R}$
In the first chapter of their Real Algebraic Geometry, Bochnak, Coste and Roy regarding Dedekind cuts of $\mathbb{R}$ and orderings of $\mathbb{R}(X)$ write as follows

Example: There is exactly one ordering of $\mathbb R(X)$ such that $X$ is positive and smaller than any positive real number. If $P(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_kX^k$ with $a_k\neq0$, then $P(X)>0$ for this ordering if and only if $a_k>0$ and $P(X)/Q(X)>0$ if and only if $P(X)Q(X)>0$.

Moreover...

Given any ordering of $\mathbb{R}(X)$, $X$ determines a cut $(I,J)$ in $\mathbb R$ where $I=\{x\in\mathbb R|x<X\}$ and $J=\{x\in\mathbb R|X<x\}$. The cuts $(\emptyset,\mathbb R)$, $(]-\infty,a[,[a,+\infty[)$, $(]-\infty,a],]a,+\infty[)$ and $(\mathbb R,\emptyset)$ are respectively denoted by $-\infty$, $a_-$, $a_+$ and $+\infty$. Performing, respectively, the change of variables $Y=-1/X$, $Y=a-X$, $Y=X-a$ and $Y=1/X$, we get an ordering of $\mathbb R(Y)$ such that $Y$ is positive an smaller than any positive real number.

My question is the following. As an exercise in some lecture notes I am trying to complete, I have to describe explicitly the ordering on $\mathbb R[X]$ corresponding to each Dedekind cut of $\mathbb R$ using the derivatives of a generic polynomial evaluated at $0$, but I am unable to do so. This is my attempt:
Let us start with $0_+$ and denote the associated ordering $\leq_{0_+}$. Consider a generic polynomial $P(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1X+a_0\in\mathbb R[X]$. Let $k\in\mathbb N$ be the smallest natural number such that $a_k\neq0$. Following the example given by the authors, to me it seems reasonable to define $\leq_{0_+}$ as follows
$$P(X)>_{0_+}0\iff\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}X^k}P(X)|_0>0\iff k!a_k>0\iff a_k>0.$$
Now, moving on to the Dedekind cut $0_-$ I thought about this solution.
$$\color{red}{P(X)>_{0_-}0\iff P(-X)>_{0_+}0}\iff\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}X^k}P(-X)|_0>0\iff (-1)^kk!a_k>0\iff (-1)^ka_k>0$$
which to me seems reasonable. I start having problems with the cuts $a_+$ with $a\neq0$ and this makes me doubt the crucial step I highlighted in red. Here is my attempt
$$P(X)>_{a_+}0\iff P(X-a)>_{0_+}0\iff\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}X^k}P(X-a)|_0>0\iff k!a_k>0\iff a_k>0.$$
But this is exactly the ordering $\leq_{0_+}$ so there must be a mistake. Obviously I get the same problem when I try with $a_-$ and I am even more lost with the cuts $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.
Thank you for your time.

You have two mistakes: $P(X-a)>{0+}0\not\Leftrightarrow\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}X^k}P(X-a)|_0>0$ (because the valuation of $P(X-a)$ may be $<k$), and $\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}X^k}P(X-a)|_0$ is much less simple than $k!a_k$.

Thank you @AnneBauval for your help, I see the mistake now. Nonetheless, I can't find a way to solve these cases. I am expecting the solution to look something like $P(X-a)>{0+}0\iff a_k-a>0$, but as you said, the evaluation of the derivative is very ugly, so I think I am far from the solution. Do you happen to have any suggestions?

Sorry, I don't. Could you please edit your post to quote word for word how the exercise is formulated in your lecture notes? Incidentally, I found a third mistake: $P(X)>{a+}0\not\Leftrightarrow P(X-a)>{0+}0$. The "change of variable" means: $P(X)>{a+}0\iff P(Y+a)>{0+}0$. For instance $X-a>{a+}0$ because $Y>{0+}0$.

@AnneBauval I have edited my post quoting the exercise sheet I am trying to solve. Unfortunately it does not make a big difference. I hope it helps.

"A generic polynomial" might be my $P(Y+a)$.

I think that this just solves the problem. I was looking for something way more complicated that it needed to be. Thank you very very much for your help @AnneBauval. Unless you wanna post it as an answer, I can summarize it and self answer the question.

Please do._____

Following Anne Bauval's advices, I post here an answer for my question:
The orderings associated with the cuts $0_+$ and $0_-$ where correct, but the rest was not. The right way to describe explicitly the ordering associated to $a_+$ with $a\neq0$ is
$$ P(X)>_{a_+}0\iff P(X-a)>_{0_+}0\iff P(Y)>_{0_+}0$$
after the substitution $X-a\mapsto Y$. Write $P(Y)=b_mY^m+b_{m-1}Y^{m-1}+\cdots+b_1Y+b_0$ and let $h$ be the smallest index such that $b_h\neq0$. Then $P(Y)>_{0_+}0\iff \frac{\mathrm d^h}{\mathrm d Y^h}P(Y)|_{Y=0}=h!b_h>0\iff b_h>0$. This, is indeed an explicit description of the ordering of $\mathbb R[X]$ as requested. The other cases are analogous, since you just have to make the other substitutions (i.e., $a-X\mapsto Y$, $-\frac{1}{X}\mapsto Y$ and $\frac{1}{X}\mapsto Y$) and then the argument is exactly the same, depending on the coefficients of the polynomial P after the substitution.
As a bonus, let us check that the ordering obtained in the case $a_+$ confirms the intuition that $a_+$ (resp. $a_-$) is a useful notation remembering where you are supposed to put $X$, i.e., $X$ is the smallest element which is greater than $a$ (resp. $X$ is the greatest element which is smaller than $a$). According to the previous statement, considering the two very simple polynomials $P(X)=X-a,\;Q(X)=a-X$ we expect $P(X)>_{a_+}0$ and $Q(X)<_{a_+}0$ (and the reverse inequalities when considering the ordering $\leq_{a_-}$).
$$P(X)>_{a_+}0\iff P(X-a)=1\cdot(X-a)>_{0_+}0$$
Thus in this case $h=1$ and we obtain
$$P(X)>_{a_+}0\iff \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d(X-a)}(X-a)=1>0.$$
which is indeed true.
Analogously for $Q(X)$ we get
$$Q(X)<_{a_+}0\iff Q(X-a)=-1\cdot(X-a)<_{0_+}0.$$
Hence also in this case $h=1$ and we obtain
$$Q(X)<_{a_+}0\iff \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d(X-a)}(-1\cdot(X-a))=1<0$$
which is also true.
I would like to thank Anne again for the useful discussion.

Again: 1) $P(X)>{a+}0\not\Leftrightarrow P(X-a)>{0+}0$ is wrong. 2) $P(X)>{a+}0\iff P(Y+a)>{0+}0$, not $P(Y)>{0+}0$.
